# Serious url rewrite problem

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i am using this rewrite rule on one of my website it works well, but i have been trying to use it on another website but it has not been working (the two website uses similar url structure)

shows page not on server

url rewrite details:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^view/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ view.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^view/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ view.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

this is the link  ' http://address.com/view/1/honda-accord-ivtec-2011 ' want to rewrite to http://address.com/view.php?id=1&title=honda-accord-ivtec-2011

Please what am i not getting right

Thanks

Comment: Change `[L]` to `[R,L]` to see where the url takes you.

Comment: @Aleksi , changed it, same 404 not found error

Comment: what was the resulting url? Was it the expected url or did you see an error? If everything went as expected, what are the permissions of the view php?

Comment: @Aleksi , i do not understand; pls clarify. If i enter ' http://address.com/view.php?id=1&title=honda-accord-ivtec-2011 ' , the page loads but if i enter  ' http://address.com/view/1/honda-accord-ivtec-2011 ', it doesnt.

Comment: Then permissions are ok. When you have the [R] attribute it should result in an external redirect that changes the URL in the browsers address bar. If the RewriteRule is correct then the URL in the browsers address bar should change to match the expected URL.

Comment: It seems the rules work ok. Are the rules applied at all? Is the .htaccess file named correctly? Is mod_rewrite present? etc

Comment: @Aleksi, following your explanation of the [R] attribute, if i enter ' address.com/view/1/honda-accord-ivtec-2011' in the address bar, if doesnt change and it displays error 500 internal server error. i think the .htaccess is named correctly (cos on my ftp client the file type is HTACCESS file. For the mod_rewrite, pls kindly explain and any other details that will help me. Thanks

Comment: 500 error tells that the .htaccess became malformed: this works `RewriteRule ^view/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ view.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^view/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ view.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,R]`, sorry for misinformation.

Comment: thanks so much, it works well now. it seems the prob is frm my end (d file am uploading); i have learnt a lot in this our chat.

Comment: @Alexsi, the page loads now, i have removed the [R] option, but it seems the page cannot access the css and picture folders, what do i do?

Comment: @Alexsi, if i remove the [R] it doesnt load css and pictures, but if i put it back it does. is there a way of achieving the rewrite, without having to do an external redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the rewrite module is not set on your Apache server. Try this in command line with Debian:

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load  /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load
```

Or this with Ubuntu:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load  /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load
```